# TFS question - joining table row based on the highest date value

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am hoping I can get some help with my TFS query. I am trying to join a table based on the highest date value with a State = 'Ready for QA'.

Here is what I have currently:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.ChangedDate, b.Id, b.[Changed Date], b.State, CASE WHEN b.[Changed Date] < a.ChangedDate AND b.State = 'Ready for QA' OR b.Id IS NULL THEN a.ChangedDate ELSE b.[Changed Date] END AS 'Ready'
  FROM [Tfs_AdmiCollection].[dbo].[tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest] a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, State, MAX(ChangedDate) AS 'Changed Date' FROM [Tfs_AdmiCollection].[dbo].[tbl_WorkItemCoreWere] WHERE State = 'Ready for QA' GROUP BY Id, State) b ON a.Id = b.Id
  WHERE a.IterationId = 312
    AND a.State = 'Ready for QA'
    AND a.WorkItemType = 'Bug'
ORDER BY Ready

SELECT * FROM [Tfs_AdmiCollection].[dbo].[tbl_WorkItemCoreWere]
WHERE Id = 24809

SELECT * FROM [Tfs_AdmiCollection].[dbo].[tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest]
WHERE Id = 24809
```

[image: Results]

In the Image, I only want to use the ChangedDate from table b in my CASE when the highest date value = 'Ready for QA'. Can anyone explain the best way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: How about using `INNER JOIN`? Could you elaborate what do you want to achieve? Which version of TFS are you using? We don't suggest query database directly, you may check [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) instead.

Comment: I was able to do what I needed to do. This question isn't valid anymore.